# Prime filters on a linear ordered lattice

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory, lattice-orders, filters

Consider a lattice algebra given by a *linear* order $(H,\leq)$. We say that $A\subseteq H$ is a prime filter if $\emptyset\neq A\neq H$ and

1. $x,y\in A$ implies $x\land y\in A$ (where $\land$ is the minimum),
2. $x\in A$, $x\leq y$ implies $y\in A$,
3. $x\lor y\in A$ implies $x\in A$ or $y\in A$ (where $\lor$ is the maximum).

The dual frame of $H$ is given by the set of all prime filters on $H$ ordered by $\subseteq$. I wonder, if $\leq$ is a linear order, if the prime filters are linearly ordered by $\subseteq$ as well. I tried to prove it several ways, but got nowhere. However, I also can't directly produce a counterexample.

Comment: $A$ doesn't appear anywhere in the three conditions for it.

Comment: @joriki A typo ... I've edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a linearly ordered lattice every proper filter is a prime filter, so it is enough to prove that the set of filters is linearly ordered too.

Now let $F$ and $G$ be filters of $H$ such that $F \nsubseteq G$, and let $a \in F \setminus G$.
Let $b \in G$, arbitrary.
Then $a \leq a \vee b$, whence $a \vee b \in F$.
If $a \vee b = a$, then $b \leq a$, yielding $a \in G$, a contradiction.
Thus $a \vee b = b \in F$ and therefore $G \subseteq F$.

Comment: May I ask how linearity is important here. From your argument, it seems at first that the set of filters is always linearly ordered by inclusion ? Is this the case or am I missing an application of linearity?

Comment: @blub The last two lines of the answer use that $a\lor b$ must be either $a$ or $b$, which wouldn't be true without linearity.

Comment: @AndreasBlass thank you very much

Comment: @blub I take it from your last comment that you understood everything now, right?

Comment: @amrsa yes and thank you as well